# Multiple file upload script with thumbnail creation not working, not getting errors

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload

Script below is not working.  Not getting any php error messages.  Had asked a similar question, changed around thumbnail creation and if I had updated that question it would not have been seen at all.

Code is not getting past file type check.  The input type of file has a name of multifile[].

```
if ((($_FILES['multifile']['type'][$key] == "image/png") || 
        ($_FILES['multifile']['type'][$key] == "image/jpeg") || 
        ($_FILES['multifile']['type'][$key] == "image/pjpeg") && 
        ($_FILES['multifile']['size'][$key] < 2097152)))
    {

        if(count($_FILES['multifile']['name'])) 
        {
            foreach ($_FILES['multifile']['name'] as $key => $filename)
            {

                $filename = time().'_'.$_FILES['multifile']['name'];  
                $source = $_FILES['multifile']['tmp_name'];  
                $target = 'uploads/'.$filename;  

                if(move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['multifile']['tmp_name'][$key],$target))
                {
                    createThumbnail($filename);  

                    //database insert here

                    echo '<div class="success" style="margin-right:25px;">Images added, view individual album to edit image descriptions</div>';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        echo '<div class="error">Invalid file, only jpg, jpeg, or png file types allowed</div>';
    }
```

Here is print_r of $_FILES

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => image1.png [1] => image2.png ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/png [1] => image/png ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/php1rPxh5 [1] => /tmp/phpsGsA2I ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 27594 [1] => 24466 ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your if to this

```
 if ((($_FILES['multifile']['type'][$key] == "image/png") || 
    ($_FILES['multifile']['type'][$key] == "image/jpeg") || 
    ($_FILES['multifile']['type'][$key] == "image/pjpeg")) && 
    ($_FILES['multifile']['size'][$key] < 2097152))
```

this makes it read as if extension is Ok AND if size is Ok

I personally believe if you are using count then use it this way

```
if(count($_FILES['multifile']['name']) >0)
```

Also if possible can you give output of print_r($_FILES['multifile'])

```
for($i=0;$i< count($_FILES['multifile']['type']);$i++){
    echo "i:".$i."<br/>";
    if ((($_FILES['multifile']['type'][$i] == "image/png") || 
    ($_FILES['multifile']['type'][$i] == "image/jpeg") || 
    ($_FILES['multifile']['type'][$i] == "image/pjpeg")) && 
    ($_FILES['multifile']['size'][$i] < 2097152))
    {
    echo "icond:".$i."<br/>";

            $filename = time().'_'.$_FILES['multifile']['name'][$i];  
            $target = 'uploads/'.$filename;  

            if(move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['multifile']['tmp_name'][$i],$target))
            {
                createThumbnail($filename);  
                echo '<div class="success" style="margin-right:25px;">Images added, view individual album to edit image descriptions</div>';
            } 
             else
            {
             echo '<div class="error">Invalid file'.$filename.', only jpg, jpeg, or png file types allowed</div>';
             }        
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give print_r result of your $_FILES array

Comment: so with my change are you still stuck at first if. where is value of first $key coming from? I can see that you are using $key for iterating `foreach ($_FILES['multifile']['name'] as $key => $filename)` too

Comment: the key is necessary I was curious if it exist at all. Alright One way to troubleshoot is to enter say `echo 1;die(0);` and move it just under your if condition to see if its getting there and then slowly move it down to see where it is failing. Other thing is to provide full path to variable `$target` e.g. `c:\uploads\filename.png` or something like this if uploads folder exits inside the current php file directory `$target=dirname(__FILE__)."/uploads/$filename"`

Comment: It's not even getting past the file type verification.. I tried as you said and no dice.

Comment: Any other thoughts of why it's not getting passed the file verification?  The single file upload version works just fine with the file type verification.

Comment: replace your code with the one that I provided above and let me know what does it print. make sure you get rid of you for loop thats outside the block of code that you provided

Comment: your code works, however; it is now skipping the validation check of the image type.  It will allow an image with the name of image1.sadf.jpg to be uploaded.  Is this an issue or is this still ok?

Comment: well as long as your image is ok type `png` `jpeg` that if will always return true